# Launch custom Gradle Android build in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

Is there an easy way to build, install, and auto-launch a custom Gradle build in Android Studio?

[image: Build android project android studio]

When I press the "Play" (Run) button in Android Studio (with a typical Android project configuration), my project builds, installs it on the proper device, and then launches the app.

[image: gradle configuration android studio]

How can I do this with specific Build/Product flavors (using Gradle)? I've gotten as far as creating a Gradle configuration that runs the task "installFlavor1." This installs correctly, but it doesn't auto-launch the app.

Comment: @Varun that solves the problem. I didn't see that. Was just about to post that I found that. If you change your comment to an answer, I'll mark it as the solution.

Comment: Sure. Added as answer.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can always select a different `buildVariant` from the `buildVariant window` on Android Studio. And then if you press the run/play button you should be able to install and run the app on your device/emulator.

[image: build variants]

And also for me running `gradlew install**` on the terminal does not launch the app. 
If that's something you are looking for then take a look at `build.gradle` and `buildhelper.gradle` [here](https://github.com/varunkochar/Trying-Android-Gradle/tree/master/ProductFlavorsAndBuildTypes/ProductFlavorsAndBuildTypes)

Comment: I consolidated our posts :)

Comment: Though when I run from play button and print logs using following, it runs both debug flavour : gradlew tasks --stacktrace –info