# Run lint when building android studio projects

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-lint

I would like to be able to run the lint task when I'm building projects with the android studio to ensure the lint rules are being followed.

I have tried using task dependencies but with no luck.  My TeamCity build server uses the build task which runs the lint task so that works great.  However, the android studio appears to use `generateDebugSources` and `compileDebugJava` tasks interchangeably when I have selected the debug build variant.

Here is what I have tried in my build.gradle:

```
assemble.dependsOn lint
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you just want to configure your Android Studio project to run the lint check before the default run configuration without affecting how your gradle tasks are configured, you can follow these steps.

1. Open the run configurations drop down and choose edit

[image]

2. Select your app run configuration

[image]

3. Press the '+' to add a new step

[image]

4. Choose "Gradle-aware Make"

[image]

5. Type 'check' and choose the option with your app module name and check.  (Mine is `:app:check`)

[image]

6. Press the up arrow to move the new `check` step before the existing `Gradle-aware make` step

[image]

Now, Android Studio will run the lint check and fail the build if any lint errors occur.

Comment: This works but ideally I wouldn't want everyone in the project to have to setup their environment this way.  Is there a way to do this with gradle?

Comment: Since this is closest to what I actually want I'm marking this as the correct answer for now.

Comment: can we setup this in gradle build somehow..?

Comment: You can setup this on gradle, kind of a hack but works. The idea is to make assemble tasks depend on lint tasks so that on every run you will also run lint. I wrote the code in an answer bellow.

Answer (score 40):

To runt lint and analyze your project, simply select `Analyze > Inspect Code`.

You should get a nice window with all issues.

[image]

Also check [Run lint in Android Studio](http://danielsaidi.wordpress.com/2013/07/31/run-lint-in-android-studio/) for more information.

---

I did a little more research, try adding this to your `build.gradle`.

```
lintOptions {
      abortOnError true
  }
```

There are many [options](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/e6a5b9c7c1bca4da402de442315b5ff1ada819c7) that you can apply to the `build.gradle`

Comment: I want to prevent compilation of the project on any lint error to ensure the lint rules are being followed.  Running a code inspection could simply be ignored and not guarantee the lint rules are being followed at compile time.

Comment: How do I append a lint call in my build.gradle?

Comment: I'm already using the abortOnError which is why the build breaks on my build server.  Android studio does not run the lint task when building a project.  How do I run the lint task when building a project?

Comment: Can you call you just call build server? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19529559/launch-custom-gradle-android-build-in-android-studio

Comment: It's not clear how building different variants solves my issue.

Comment: I don't want to run the lint task manually, I want it to be run when making the project.

Answer (score 28):

To do this in build.gradle, add the following lines to your build.gradle:

```
android {
  applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        def lintTask = tasks["lint${variant.name.capitalize()}"]
        output.assemble.dependsOn lintTask
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

This makes all of your assemble tasks depend on the lint task effectively running them before every assemble call that is executed by Android Studio.

**Edit**

With Android Gradle Plugin 3.3 and Gradle 5.x this is a revised version using Kotlin script:

```
applicationVariants.all {
  val lintTask = tasks["lint${name.capitalize()}"]
  assembleProvider.get().dependsOn.add(lintTask)
}
```

Comment: Worked for me when using the Android Studio play button (Run 'app') but not when using the "Make Project" button.

Comment: @Travis I don't know about Make Project TBH. AFAIK it should run the assemble command which should depend on the lint command. But I would have another try.

Comment: This is now outdated with Plugin 3.3. and Gradle 5.x

Comment: Could not set unknown property 'lintTask' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl.

Comment: @RushabhShah - this is Kotlin script right? for Groovy, use `def` instead of `val`

Comment: It does not give unused methods and datatype.

Comment: @NikhilKatekhaye - not sure I understand your comment here...

Comment: Unused methods and unused data types are not getting from it after rebuilding the project.

Comment: @NikhilKatekhaye - I see what you mean. Yeah, I guess since they are stripped out, they will not be part of the linting process. I haven't looked into gradle build for a while so I can't offer much help I am afraid.

Answer (score 12):

just run the "check" task

```
./gradlew clean check assembleRelease
```

Comment: This answers how I run a check task from the command line, not from android studio.

Comment: This is the best answer because you can do this in Jenkins too. Thank you.

Comment: Well, this might be the best answer for a different question.

Answer (score 6):

here is my solution which also works when you click *Build* - *Make Project* in Android Studio:

```
android {
..
    afterEvaluate {
        applicationVariants.all {
            variant ->
                // variantName: e.g. Debug, Release
                def variantName = variant.name.capitalize()
                // now we tell gradle to always start lint after compile
                // e.g. start lintDebug after compileDebugSources
                project.tasks["compile${variantName}Sources"].doLast {
                    project.tasks["lint${variantName}"].execute()
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer!! Something that I'm looking for. However, it gives me the below error `Could not find method execute() for arguments [] on task ':app:lintDebug' of type com.android.build.gradle.tasks.LintPerVariantTask.`

Comment: Thanks! You save my life!

Comment: The execute method was removed on the recent version of Gradle, here is the alternative which work for me : `project.tasks["compile${variantName}Sources"].dependsOn("lint${variantName}")`

Answer (score 5):

If you want to force Android Studio project to run the lint check before the default run configuration without affecting how your gradle tasks are configured, AND you want to do this in the gradle build system, then you can add the following block outside of the `android` block in the app module's build.gradle as follows:

```
android {
....
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError true
    }
}

tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name == 'compileDevDebugSources') {
        task.dependsOn lint
        task.mustRunAfter lint
    }
}
```

Replace `compileDevDebugSources`  with the desired build variant that you have already defined, eg. `compileReleaseSources`, `compileDebugSources`, `compileStagingDebugSources`, etc.

This was tested working on Android Studio 3.0

Comment: How can I apply this to all my build variants without listing all the task names?

Answer (score 4):

Just modifying answer of @Yoel Gluschnaider

For me if I use Val it shows error like this :
Could not set unknown property 'lintTask' for object of type `com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl`.

So I replace it

```
applicationVariants.all {
    def lintTask = tasks["lint${name.capitalize()}"]
    assembleProvider.get().dependsOn.add(lintTask)
}
```

and it work fine!!

Comment: I wrote my answer for Kotlin script. This is Groovy :)

Answer (score 2):

More performant answers follow Gradle [task configuration avoidance](https://docs.gradle.org/4.10/userguide/task_configuration_avoidance.html) is as below

Gradle kts version

```kotlin
android {
    applicationVariants.configureEach {
        val variantName =
            name.replaceFirstChar { if (it.isLowerCase()) it.titlecase(Locale.ENGLISH) else it.toString() }
        val lintTaskName = "lint$variantName"
        val lintTask = tasks.named("lint$variantName")
        assembleProvider.dependsOn(lintTask)
    }
}
```

Groovy version

```
android {
    applicationVariants.configureEach {
        def variantName = name.capitalize()
        def lintTaskName = "lint$variantName"
        def lintTask = tasks.named("lint$variantName")
        assembleProvider.configure {
            dependsOn lintTask
        }
    }
}
```

Pros:

1. Didn't call `assembleProvider.get()` which defeats the purpose of configuration avoidance
2. Lint task is accessed using a named function which lazily accesses the task when it is required(mentioned at Gradle migration [guide](https://docs.gradle.org/4.10/userguide/task_configuration_avoidance.html#sec:how_do_i_get_a_task))
3. Uses `configureEach` which configure each task when required rather than eagarly

Comment: If I understand your solution correctly, ```gradle kts``` version should be ```assembleProvider.dependsOn(lintTask, tasks.named(lintTaskName))```.  Please correct it.

Comment: My original solution also adds the `detekt` task. So if you just want to add lint if would be `assembleProvider.dependsOn(lintTask)`