# Promote `MissingTranslation` to error in AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, lint

In Android Studio the debug build compiles and runs without any problems.  When we do a release build on our build machine however, it fails the build because of translation strings that are missing.

Log gives

```
strings.xml:30: Error: "OrderFilterHint" is not translated in "es" (Spanish), "pt" (Portuguese) [MissingTranslation]
```

I want these errors to appear on debug builds so developers can pick it up before breaking the release build.

I have tried editing `lint.xml` to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lint>
    <issue id="MissingTranslation" severity="error" />
</lint>
```

and adding the following to my `build.gradle`

```
android {
 ...
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds true
        enable 'MissingTranslation'
    }
}
```

None of the above seems to have helped.

How can I force the `MissingTranslation` lint check to fail my debug builds?

Answer (score 0):

With gradle, it is generally ideal to use the `lintOptions` since it lets you fine tune warnings/errors as well as changing severity. From the [lint options user-guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide), you can add `error 'MissingTranslation'` to the lintOptions section.

Edit: If you want check/lint to be run when calling assembleDebug you can make the task depend on it.

e.g: add the following to gradle

```
assembleDebug.dependsOn lint
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this doesn't solve my problem. The lint check is only run when I run a `:check:` gradle build. http://stackoverflow.com/a/27068675/8524

Comment: updated the answer w/ a dependsOn task which can ensure that lint is run while running assembleDebug. Is that what you were looking for?