# timber lint: ClassNotFound: com/android/tools/lint/detector/api/Detector$JavaPsiScanner

Tags: android, lint, timber-android

The [Timber](https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber) (V 4.5.0) lint checks only work via Gradle (but not via the `lint` command and also not in Android Studio Version 2.3 Beta2).

**Summary**

When I run `lint` directly on the command line I get an error.

```
lint --show TimberArgCount

Could not load custom rule jar file /home/tmtron/.android/lint/timber-lint.jar
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/tools/lint/detector/api/Detector$JavaPsiScanner
```

but it works when I invoke it via gradle:

```
./gradlew lint

MainActivity.java:15: Error: Wrong argument count, 
format string %s.%s requires 2 but format call supplies 1 [TimberArgCount]
        Timber.d("%s.%s", "onCreate");
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

**Detailed description**

I've made a small sample project on GitHub: [TimberLintTest](https://github.com/tmtron/TimberLintTest)

Basically I did this:

- created a simple Android project in Android Studio
- added Timber
- activated stdout output for lint errors

  `android {
      lintOptions {
          textReport true
          textOutput "stdout"
      }
  }`

In the [MainActivity](https://github.com/tmtron/TimberLintTest/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/tmtron/timberlinttest/MainActivity.java#L15) I use an erronous log-statement like this:

```
Timber.d("%s.%s", "onCreate");
```

When I execute lint via the Gradle-wrapper from the command line it works as expected - stripped output:

```
MainActivity.java:15: Error: Wrong argument count, 
format string %s.%s requires 2 but format call supplies 1 [TimberArgCount]
        Timber.d("%s.%s", "onCreate");
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

But the checks don't work in Android Studio and also not when I start `lint` directly.
Some sources in the internet indicate that we must copy the `lint.jar` file to `~/.android/lint`. I did that for the lint.jar (from `timber-4.5.0`) and renamed it to `timber-lint.jar`, so that I end up with this file:

```
~/.android/lint/timber-lint.jar
```

So the problem is that this `JavaPsiScanner` **interface** is **not found**.

I have checked the Timber source code and it depends on the `lint-api-25.0.2` where the `Detector` contains this inner interface. But in my local SDK code (`Android/Sdk/tools/lib/lint-api.jar`) this inner class does not exist (I guess this is what the `lint` command line tool and Android Studio use).

So I think it's just a version mismatch. But I am not sure how to resolve this.
How can I even know for sure, which version of `lint-api.jar` my current android tools have?

When start the sdk manager and it shows that the Android SDK Tools version is 25.2.5 (I've updated to the most recent version). So is this the version of the `lint-api.jar` (or is it the *SDK platform-tools*, *SDK build-tools*, ..)?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround we can tell gradle to always run the lint checks after compilation. Then the lint checks will also be executed after you press *Build* - *Make Project* in Android Studio, which solves my original problem.

Gradle details are in [this SO-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41932970/6287240).

Answer (score 0):

Change Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.0 or newer

Answer (score 0):

defaultPublishConfig/flavor should not be 'debug' when running lint. 
For running lint on Debug variant use

> gradlew lintDebug

Refer to [Improve your code with lint checks](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint#commandline)