# Type safety using IntDef

Tags: java, android, annotations

I am trying to replace some of the enumerations in my source with IntDef annotation. I have been following  [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/IntDef.html) documentation.

I have a variable for holding a ViewMode which was previously an enumeration. Now I have changed it to some thing like below.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@IntDef({ViewMode.VIEW_MODE_LIST_VIEW, ViewMode.VIEW_MODE_CARD_VIEW})
public @interface ViewMode {
    int VIEW_MODE_LIST_VIEW = 0;
    int VIEW_MODE_CARD_VIEW = 1;
}

@ViewMode
public int currentViewMode = ViewMode.VIEW_MODE_LIST_VIEW;
```

Now to test whether this is  safe or not I have done the following in a method

```
this.currentViewMode = 987; //currentViewMode should be 0 or 1. Nothing else.
```

But this is now not giving me a compilation error. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Do you mean "now giving me a compilation error" (which is what you wrote), or "**not** giving me a compilation error"?

Comment: @mernst Thanks for pointing it out. It was a mistake. Corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not get a compilation error, because the enumerated annotations are just lint checks: see [Improve Your Code with Lint](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/annotations.html#enum-annotations)

You should see the error-marker directly in Android Studio or when you run android lint checks from the command line: see [Improve Your Code with Lint](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint.html#commandline)

Note: you can also configure your build to automatically run the lint checks:
see [SO: Run lint when building android studio projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850333/run-lint-when-building-android-studio-projects)
But running the linter takes some time, so you may choose to run it only for your release builds or only on your CI server.