# Building signed APK fails

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin

I have an app that works flawlessly in standard mode, but when trying to build signed APK it fails with this (truncated) stacktrace that tells absolutely nothing. Any help appreciated!

`gradlew lint` gives "BUILD SUCCESFUL"

```
Unexpected failure during lint analysis (this is a bug in lint or one of the libraries it depends on)
```

After upgrading to gradle plugin 3.1.0-alpha07 the error changed to something more readable:

```
e: [kapt] An exception occurred: android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: failure, see logs for details.
Could not merge in Bindables from C:\Dane\Projekty\Livecycle\app\build\intermediates\data-binding-compiler\release\dependent-lib-artifacts\com.android.databinding.library.baseAdapters-com.android.databinding.library.baseAdapters-layoutinfo.bin java.io.InvalidClassException: android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessExpressions$IntermediateV1; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 9120768259354515600, local class serialVersionUID = 2471044633310257816
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:616)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1829)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1713)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1829)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1713)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1986)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
    at android.databinding.tool.util.GenerationalClassUtil.fromInputStream(GenerationalClassUtil.java:143)
    at android.databinding.tool.util.GenerationalClassUtil.loadFromDirectory(GenerationalClassUtil.java:121)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1251)
    at android.databinding.tool.util.GenerationalClassUtil.loadFromBuildInfo(GenerationalClassUtil.java:107)
    at android.databinding.tool.util.GenerationalClassUtil.buildCache(GenerationalClassUtil.java:92)
    at android.databinding.tool.util.GenerationalClassUtil.loadObjects(GenerationalClassUtil.java:77)
    at android.databinding.tool.store.SetterStore.load(SetterStore.java:183)
    at android.databinding.tool.store.SetterStore.get(SetterStore.java:175)
    at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessMethodAdapters.onHandleStep(ProcessMethodAdapters.java:67)
    at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding$ProcessingStep.runStep(ProcessDataBinding.java:198)
    at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding$ProcessingStep.access$000(ProcessDataBinding.java:183)
    at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding.process(ProcessDataBinding.java:78)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ProcessorWrapper.process(annotationProcessing.kt:133)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:794)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:705)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1800(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:91)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1035)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1176)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1170)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1068)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:89)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing$default(annotationProcessing.kt:46)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.runAnnotationProcessing(Kapt3Extension.kt:221)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:177)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:90)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM$analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$2.invoke(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:97)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:107)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:84)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:376)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:67)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:367)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:132)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:162)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:63)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:109)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:53)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:92)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:387)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:97)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:895)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:97)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.DummyProfiler.withMeasure(PerfUtils.kt:137)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.checkedCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:925)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.doCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:894)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:386)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:346)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: have you tried running lint? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850333/run-lint-when-building-android-studio-projects#22853348

Comment: gradlew lint gives "BUILD SUCCESFUL"

Comment: Looks like https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70313727 ?

Comment: A bit, but my error seems to be connected to data binding!

Comment: @ssuukk Data binding also needs to process your code, which is where a certain version of UAST fails, so it is probably the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

When your app will reach more the 64k methods at the time will get multidex issue, so you can do below steps to solve the problem

The solution :

in the build.gradle

defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

Details : https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Comment: It's already multidex app. It must be some bug, because there are 369 jars created.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [ephemient's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20713/ephemient) comment I solved same problem by upgrading gradle from `3.0.0` to `3.1.3`:

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'`