# Merging different buildType tasks name of Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

Following https://stackoverflow.com/a/48494454/3286489, I could now run the linting tasks (both in CLI and run in Android Studio) before compile my app.

My code as below.

```
android {
//....
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError true
    }
}

tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name == 'compileDebugSources' || task.name == 'compileReleaseSources') {
        task.dependsOn lint
        task.mustRunAfter lint
    }
}
```

However I dislike

```
task.name == 'compileDebugSources' || task.name == 'compileReleaseSources'
```

Is there a way to combine them and still get it working?

Comment: I could also use `task.name.startsWith('compile') && task.name.endsWith('Sources')` but still not nice.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex :

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name.matches('compile(.*)Sources')) {
        task.dependsOn lint
        task.mustRunAfter lint
    }
}
```