# How to solve linter crashing during build analysis?

Tags: android, gradle, console, lint

I have installed an Android Studio, export project  and project is building correctly. But I am trying to build the same project in terminal. I run `./gradlew build` in terminal, and gets errors.

````
> Task :UniterModule:lintDebug FAILED
Lint found 20 errors, 129 warnings. First failure:

/uniter/repo/repo_pull/mobile/UniterModule/src/main/java/com/uniter/mobile/ui/activities/BaseActivity.kt: Error: Unexpected failure during lint analysis of BaseActivity.kt (this is a bug in lint or one of the libraries it depends on)


The full lint text report is located at:
  /uniter/repo/repo_pull/mobile/UniterModule/build/intermediates/lint_intermediate_text_report/debug/lint-results-debug.txt

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':UniterModule:lintDebug'.
> Lint found errors in the project; aborting build.
  
  Fix the issues identified by lint, or create a baseline to see only new errors:
  ```
  android {
      lint {
          baseline = file("lint-baseline.xml")
      }
  }
  ```
  
  For more details, see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint#snapshot
````

Building in terminal is successful when i use ./gradlew -x lint

Settings on Android Studio are:

[Gradle JDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hZPM.png)

[Android Gradle Plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7t354.png)

[Modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOmYf.png)

Settings on PC:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.3.3
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2021-12-22 12:37:54 UTC
Revision:     6f556c80f945dc54b50e0be633da6c62dbe8dc71

Kotlin:       1.5.31
Groovy:       3.0.9
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          11.0.2 (Oracle Corporation 11.0.2+9)
OS:           Linux 5.13.0-40-generic amd64
```

I set in .bashrc path to Android SDK

```
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT="/home/kamil/Android/Sdk/"
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
```

Could You tell me where is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The build is failed because there are problems in the project which were found by the static analyser (lint).

You can:

- fix the reported issues (the report file path can be found under the "The full lint text report is located at:" line in the output)
- ignore issues by using the `@SuppressLint` annotation or specifying them in the `lint.xml` file
- ignore the lint status during build by specifying the following flag in the `build.gradle` file:

```
android {
...
  lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
  }
}
```

- specify a baseline with the current lint status in the `build.gradle` file:

```
android {
...
  lintOptions {
    baseline file("lint-baseline.xml")
  }
}
```

See https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint for further details.

Comment: I don't want to suppress issue, as I wrote there is no issue when building by android studio, building project is successful. I would like to know hot to set linux to build project like android studio.

Comment: The static analysis (lint) is not part of the Android Studio build by default. Android Studio does not use the "gradle build" command but "gradle assembleDebug" or something similar. You can run the checks manually inside the IDE from the Code > Inspect Code... menu. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850333/run-lint-when-building-android-studio-projects

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar issue.

In my case, a custom class such as `BaseActivity.kt` here could be, was missing the `package` information at the top of the file.

Setting the package and running linter again fixed the issue instead of simply bypassing the error/warning.